# Sticking a form on another form running in different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have an info form which displays information about some process status. This form is displayed over a main form where user gives instruction for process execution. Now, I run this info form on a different thread and unable to stick it on top of the main form. Whenever I click on show desktop button at bottom right corner of the taskbar and then try to restore my application from the taskbar, the info form is not visible. How can I make this info form remain sticked to the main form?

Comment: When/If you call [showdialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe.aspx), you can pass in an owner form. That should tie the parent to the child dialog. Are you passing your main form into the showdialog method?

Comment: Open as modal dialog. Why you create UI element in thread rather than UI thread?

Comment: could you please explain a bit?

Comment: coz the code has been written long ago. I am only adding some ui functionality which is not running properly on main thread.

Comment: sorry, my initial answer wasn't clear. I've clarified my answer.

Comment: Also keep in mind what other are saying about the UI thread. You can only update your UI if you're in the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is a clean way of doing it, but it does the job!

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Resize += OnResize;
    }

    private void OnResize(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (form2running && form != null && (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized || WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal))
        {
            form.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal));
        }
    }


    private bool form2running = false;
    private Form form;

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ShowNewForm);
    }

    private void ShowNewForm(object o)
    {
        form2running = true;
        form = new Form2();
        Application.Run(form);
        form2running = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All forms of application should run on a single UI thread. Use background thread (e.g. via [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)) if you want to perform some operation in background. Just refresh UI of your info form when new data arrives from background thread.

Take a look at [Multithreading in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951089.aspx)

Keep in mind that winforms controls are [not thread-safe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> Access to Windows Forms controls is not inherently thread safe. If you
>   have two or more threads manipulating the state of a control, it is
>   possible to force the control into an inconsistent state. Other
>   thread-related bugs are possible as well, including race conditions
>   and deadlocks. It is important to ensure that access to your controls
>   is done in a thread-safe way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your info form and initialize it in separate thread, but then you have to show it in your main thread. You can't normally operate between two forms running in separate threads.

Consider to use [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to perform your task.